# $L_{1}(\Omega ,\Sigma ,\mu )$ is not reflexive

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\Sigma ,\mu )$ be a positive measure space. We have a countable measurable set denoted by $\{E_{n}\}$, $E_{n}$ is disjoint with $E_{m}$ when $n\neq m$, and $0<\mu (E_{n}) < \infty$.
How to prove that $L_{1}(\Omega ,\Sigma ,\mu )$ is not reflexive?

I know the the traditional way to show when Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, by show $L_{\infty}$ is not separable by constructing some functions. But I can’t use the same way on this question.
I known when a Banach space is reflexive, any bounded sequence must have a subsequence which is weakly convergent.

Comment: The dual of $L^1(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is $L^\infty(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$.  The same proof that you know for $l^\infty(\Bbb{N})$ works by using the characteristic functions $\{\mathbf{1}_{E_n}\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ in place of the basis vectors $\{e_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ of $l^\infty(\Bbb{N})$.

Answer (score 2):

Define $T:\ell^{1} \to L^{1}(\mu)$ by $T(a_n)=\sum \frac {a_n} {\mu(E_n)} 1_{E_n}$. Then $T$ is an isometric isomorphism onto its range, so $L^{1}$ has a closed subspace which is not reflexive. It follows that $L^{1}(\mu)$ not reflexive.